# How to prove $\Phi_w(x)=\cos (w^T x+b)$ is outside the RKHS associated with the Gaussian kernel function$K(x,y)=\exp(-\frac{||x-y||^2}{2\sigma})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, machine-learning

How to prove $\Phi_w (x)=\cos (w^T x+b)$ is outside the RKHS ( Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space) associated with the Gaussian kernel function$K(x,y)=\exp(-\frac{||x-y||^2}{2\sigma})$？

Comment: What do you mean by "is outside". Could you write it mathematically?

Comment: 'is outside' means 'is not in',:)

Comment: um, can someone help?